# Split y-axis with plotly?

Tags: plotly-python, yaxis

Is it possible to have a split Y-axis to better depict all values including outliners in Plotly?

For example like in the picture below

[image]

Comment: Short answer is: No

Comment: Thanks. What is the long answer?

Comment: Well there are several alternatives. If you want the break, use e.g. *plotrix* or *ggplot*. If you want to stick to *plotly*, you could for example use a logarithmic scale on the y axis.

Comment: Solved here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65766964/14672356