# How to visualize bar charts with large range of values better (R Plotly)?

Tags: r, plotly, bar-chart

I am trying to visualize my data using bar plots in the `plotly` package in R. My data has a large range due to which some of the smaller values get smashed to the floor, which is expected. I would like to know if there is a better way to present data with such large ranges. Here is an example of what I am referring to:

```
cost<- c(10,100,5,6,1,0.2)
fruits<-c("Apple","Grapes","Orange","Mango","Banana","Peach")
fruit_data <- data.frame(fruits,cost)
Bar_Plot <- plot_ly(fruit_data, x = ~fruits, y = ~cost,textposition='auto',type = 'bar') %>% layout(title="Cost of Fruits",xaxis=list(title='Fruits'),yaxis = list(title = 'cost',range=c(0,105)))
show(Bar_Plot)
```

Here is a visualization of the above code. As you can see, the cost of peach and banana is quite close to the figure's floor and hard to differentiate in terms of cost. I know I can display the actual values above each bar, but I am looking for ways to visually exaggerate smaller values. I am also open to other methods of visualization. Thank you so much for your feedback and suggestions.

[image]

Comment: One very powerful solution and a standard answer is a log axis, but you loose so much of the intuitivity. Simply switching to horizontal bars will increase the room for bar lengths if you stay with landscape orientation of your graphic.Or do indeed print to different views of you data with different axis limits.

Comment: I will try doing the horizontal option, the log option will remove the qualitative sense from my data unfortunately.

Comment: Another way is to remove `Grapes` from the plot and in your descriptive text go along with plot describe the outliner and their value. In case you have multiple outliner you may want to graph them separately as clearly they are on different categories. With interactive like plotly you can add the filter feature which would remove one element and auto scale Y-Axis.

Comment: @AdityaLahiri How about a [gap in the y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65669385/plotly-r-how-to-make-a-gapped-y-axis/65766833#65766833)?

Comment: @SinhNguyen I have considered removing the outliers and having two plots as you suggested. I am not familiar with `Grapes`, is it a keyword or package in R?

Comment: @vestland: That is an interesting solution. I may end up using this, seems very practical.

Comment: @AdityaLahiri Thanks for the feedback. Just ask in a comment on that post if anything is unclear.

Comment: @AdityaLahiri the `Grapes` I mean is the one of the Fruits in your plot.

Comment: @SinhNguyen I see, ok, thanks for the clarification. I am trying to retain the outliers. For my specific context, the cost of the fruit is more of a desired feature, so unfortunately I can't remove it.